# Rails Controller: how do you account for optional and required parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the tutorials I have seen, create has been implemented like this:

```
def create
  @note = Note.new(note_params)

  @note.save
  redirect_to @note
end

private
  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :type, :description, :dueDate)
  end
```

I have read about the fetch method for optional parameters, but how do I mix the two methods to require some parameters and permit others?  Would it be like this:

```
private
  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :type)
    params.fetch(:note, {}).permit(:description, :dueDate)
  end
```

In this case, could I expect to pass 0, 1, or 2 of the fetched params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading it wrong, I think. In this line

```
 params.require(:note).permit(:title, :type, :description, :dueDate)
```

The required parameter is `:note`. And `:title`, `:type` and others are simply permitted/allowed to appear under `:note`. None of them are *required* by this syntax. If you really need `:title` to be there, that is best handled by presence validation on your Note model.

```
class Note
  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

Now, if you don't pass `params[:note][:title]`, `@note.save` will return false and you can render form with user-friendly errors (highlight missing fields, etc.). You wouldn't be able to do that (as easily) if `note_params` method raised an exception on missing title attribute. So that is how you handle required record attributes in rails.

Comment: I see.  Thanks a lot!  I have been having a time finding a rails tutorial that properly explains these things.